# Joomla doesn't show my language characters

Tags: joomla

When I post link to my article on Facebook, then Facebook loads a part of site, so I can see some text from this article, but I get "poniedziaÅek", but should be "poniedziałek" it just doesn't show polish characters. I have set up

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
```

but nothing, still have some weird characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try experimenting with unicode alias settings in joomla global configuration.

Also take a look at these:

- [Problem with facebook and polish characters in links](http://www.gavick.com/forums/league-news/problem-with-facebook-and-polish-characters-in-links-21772.html)
- [Non ASCII-7 characters in URL (article alias)](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=253744)
- [Unicode urls](http://docs.joomla.org/International_Enhancements_for_Version_1.6#Unicode_URLs)